# $BASH_VERSION vs /usr/bin/env

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I run this to check env:

```
env | grep bash
```

and then got nothing.

So, I think the variable `bash` is not set in env. However, in a shell script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $BASH_VERSION
```

I got `5.1.16(1)-release`.

It seems contradictory because, on the one hand, I think the variable `bash` must have been set as the shell script file can be executed in a manner as expected; on the other hand, running `env | grep bash`, I got nothing.

How could the OS locate the app bash-5.1.16 without an env variable being set?

Comment: **BASH_VERSION is a shell variable but not an environment variable.** Only shell variables that are marked 'export' are environment variables, and only environment variables are passed to a child process like `env`. Note that it doesn't make sense to export it because you might run a different shell, or a different version of bash, as a child process, in which case an exported variable's value would be badly wrong. But even if it had been passed to env, you grepped for `bash` in lowercase, which DOES NOT MATCH uppercase unless you use flag `-i`.

Comment: Sorry but maybe I failed to express my question clearly. `env | grep bash` got nothing, then how could the OS find the path to bash 5.1.16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$BASH_VERSION` is not an environment variable but a shell variable.
You can see defined shell variable with the `declare` builtin.

```
declare | grep BASH_VERSION
```

> BASH_VERSION='5.1.4(1)-release'

The `env` program is used to run a program with modified environment.
Running `/usr/bin/env bash` without arguments is basically the same as running `bash`, it's ensure that the program is on the file system and not a shell builtin.

Comment: The BASH_VERSION is set when bash is started. If you get a result when you do $BASH_VERSION, then you are already in bash with the given version.

Comment: env | grep bash, I expect there should be a variable named 'bash' in env because shellbang uses it to locate the app bash-5.1.4

Comment: `env bash` is not the same as `env | grep bash`. As I said in my answer, the `BASH_VERSION` is not in the env,   Doing `env bash` run bash, and bash declare a shell variable, BASH_VERSION, that you can get by doing `declare | grep BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: When you do `env bash`, the shell will search a binary named "bash" to execute by searching in directories in the `PATH` environment variable. The shell will generally found a binary named "bash" in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.